# Converting a text file into CSV or storing each value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, logfile

```
SampNum            Acc_X              Acc_Y              Acc_Z  
1                  0.89304            0.00366            -0.247416
2                   0.89304             0.00366          -0.247416
3                   0.887184            0.008052            -0.240096
```

I have a log file something like this and I need to convert it to a csv file or just pick up every field and save it to mysql table with the columns name SampNum, etc along with the corresponding values.

How can I do it with php?

Comment: Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with more information, sample code, and the steps you have taken so far. This information will make it more likely that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLEASE:

- Don't use the deprecated ext/mysql, when you can use ext/mysqli or PDO.
- Don't read the entire csv file into a PHP variable. What happens when the file is 500MB?
- Don't write custom PHP code to parse csv data, when you can use the builtin function fgetcsv().
- Don't create a new SQL statement for every row in the data, when you can use prepared statements.
- Don't interpolate data from an external file into SQL statements. This risks SQL injection vulnerabilities, just like when you interpolate untrusted user input.
- Don't parse and insert csv data row by row, when you can use MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE command. It's 20x faster than inserting row by row.

Here's a simpler solution:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost"; 
$databasename = "test"; 
$databasetable = "sample"; 
$databaseusername="test"; 
$databasepassword = ""; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\n";
$csvfile = "filename.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
        $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
      LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

Comment: I dont have a csv file.its just a log file and spaces between them.. I want to convert the log file into the csv file.in short i want to remove the spaces and add comma(,) between them so it will become csv file

Comment: If there is a fixed number of spaces you can set `$fieldseparator = '        ' //Add as many spaces as there are`. `$csvfile` would be your file. The extension is not fixed. Even a *.log file will be read if it is in proper format

Comment: No the number of spaces are not fixed.it contains almost 40 thousand rows and every row has a different value e.g if i have a value 0.89304  and after some values there are values like 0 and 0.10 etc so number of spaces differ..